# How to scrape a XML website using bs4?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am parsing websites which sell electronic products..
Specifically, I am looking to collect the name and the price of the product
I ran into a small problem when parsing a xml based site....

Here is my code:

```
>>> import urllib2  
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
>>> url=urllib2.urlopen("http://store.explorelabs.com/index.php?main_page=products_all")  
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(url,"xml")  
>>> data=soup.find_all(colspan="2")
```

The code above works
now when I do this (as the name is inside the strong tags)

```
>>> data.strong
```

or

```
>>> data.attrs
```

It shows me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>  
    data.strong  
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'strong'
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>  
    data.find_all('a')  
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I am trying to iterate and try to find out more.
Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've formatted your code blocks for you; review [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for help next time.

Comment: Also note that on Stack Overflow, we can all help improve your posts by editing them. If you roll back those edits, you undo the work of those that are trying to help you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i am so sorry, thanks for the friendliness :)

Answer (score 1):

`find_all` returns a list of elements that match, not one. Loop over the result set to get the individual items:

```
for element in data:
    element.attrs
```

Comment: Hey can you give me help how to go about collecting the price of the product?
(sometimes there is a Manufacturer's name as well in some product listing and sometimes there isn't and the product information's are seperated by a br tag)

Comment: Study the BeautifulSoup documentation, play with the library some more, I'm sure you'll figure it out. If you come up against concrete problems, search here on Stack Overflow (there are loads of BeautifulSoup answers here), and if you cannot find the answer to your problem, ask a new question.